# VBA Replace Code in Another Module Using VBA Code

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a line of code in one module:

```
City = "Paris"
```

Within a separate module I need to change the name of the city based on what a user selects from a dropdown. I have code that will change the entire line as follows:

```
Sub ChangeUserCity()
Call Dictionary.CityLocation
Dim UserChosenCity As String
Dim SL As Long, EL As Long, SC As Long, EC As Long
Dim S As String
Dim Found As Boolean

ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(CityName)) 'This is the name of the combodropdown box with the list of city names.

For Each Ky In ComboBoxList
'On Error Resume Next

UserChosenCity = dict4.Item(Ky)(0) 'This refers to the dictionary that has the list of city names. It grabs the string (the name of the city).

With ActivePresentation.VBProject.VBComponents("Dictionary").CodeModule
SL = 1
SC = 1
EL = -1
EC = -1
Found = .Find("City = " & """" & "Paris" & """", SL, SC, EL, EC, True, False, False)
If Found = True Then
S = .Lines(SL, 1)
S = Replace(S, "City = " & """" & "Paris" & """", "City= " & """" & UserChosenCity & """")
.ReplaceLine SL, S
End If
End With
Next Ky
End Sub
```

The problem with the way this code works is that the city name will not always be "Paris". It could be any string (i.e. any city name). So what I really need the code to do is just replace the city name between the quotes with the UserChosenCity. Any idea on how to accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: If the user selects the city name from a drop-down why not use that value rather than changing the code?  Store the selected value in a variable and use the variable in the line of code rather than a static value.

Comment: Actually, I remember why now! haha The user does not have to select a city each time the PPT starts up. If they select it once, I need it to be remembered and saved with the PPT file.

Comment: Not sure how to store values in PPT, but still must be a better way than changing the code.  How about writing it to a hidden textbox on a slide?

Comment: To save values to a PPT file, use Tags.  For example:  ActivePresentation.Tags.Add "CityName", "Paris"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a combo box and a text box to your slide.

With ComboBox1 and TextBox1 on Slide 1 this code moves the value from the combobox to the the textbox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim oComboBox As ComboBox
    Dim oTextBox As TextBox

    Set oComboBox = ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("ComboBox1").OLEFormat.Object
    Set oTextBox = ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object

    oTextBox.Value = oComboBox.Value

    'or

    Slide1.TextBox1.Value = Slide1.ComboBox1.Value

End Sub
```

**Note:** Powerpoint isn't my forte so there may be a "proper" way to store values in PPT.

You can now retrieve the value from the textbox after the presentation has been saved, closed and re-opened (saying that - the combobox also retained the value when I re-opened it) and use that value in elsewhere in your code.

Comment: That's a good idea. Like you said, there is probably a better way, but this will definitely do the job. Thanks a lot!